# How do I achieve tilde expansion in C?

Tags: c

`chdir("~/")` doesn't seem to work.  Am I expected to look at the string and substitute tilde by hand, or is there some better way?

Comment: I want to say that is built in to a shell.  Shouldn't be to difficult to roll your own.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

POSIX provides [`wordexp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) to perform shell-like expansion, including tilde expansion.

Answer (score 19):

You can you use [`wordexp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) example below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wordexp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    wordexp_t exp_result;
    wordexp(argv[1], &exp_result, 0);
    printf("%s\n", exp_result.we_wordv[0]);
}
```

Comment: If you use this in a function, you'll want to add `wordfree(&exp_result);` to avoid leaking memory.

Answer (score 9):

The tilde in a path is a shell specific thing. What you can do see if the first character is a tilde and a slash (or a tilde end end of the string), then replace the tilde with the value of the environment variable `HOME` (which you can get from [`getenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getenv.html)).

If the second character is *not* a slash, it's most likely in the form of `~user/path`. Then you have to extract the user-name and use e.g. [`getpwnam`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwnam.html) to get the password entry of the user, which contains that users home directory.