# How do I get relative or absolute file path stored in hpp header files, that can be used in any system?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I want to store the absolute path of a folder in an hpp file; the path is stored in a public class. I tried using: 
    `static constexpr const char* FOLDER_PATH = "$HOME/catkin_ws/src/abc/pqr/xyz"`

But, that `$HOME` seems to be not working. Can I get a workaround that `$HOME`? If I write `/home/myname/` it seems to be working fine. I do not want to write `/home/myname/`; **the issue is I need to change every time I run that code on different systems**. I do not want to edit every time; the folder structure remains the same.

Comment: `$HOME` gets substituted by the SHELL, not the programs and they happen **before** you start the program. However, with [wordexp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) you can do it in C and C++. But this function is not part of the standard library, is a POSIX function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I achieve tilde expansion in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991241/how-do-i-achieve-tilde-expansion-in-c)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/

Comment: All those answers are bad though. You don't need shell expansion to get the home directory, and `wordexp` doesn't work on Windows. There's a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cross-Platform Home Directory in C++**

To get the HOME directory at runtime (meaning it cannot be determined at compile-time, so it cannot be stored as a constant in a header), you may use `getenv` (or on Windows, `_wgetenv`, since paths should be Unicode-aware and therefore use the wide API on Windows).

**POSIX**

You may assume the path is specified using the `HOME` environment variable.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

std::string get_home()
{
    char *dir = getenv("HOME");
    if (dir != nullptr) {
        return std::string(dir);
    } else {
        // home not defined, root user, maybe return "/root"
        // this code path should generally **not** occur.  
        return std::string("/");
    }
}
```

**Windows**

A simple solution, as suggested by Miles Budnek, is to use `GetUserProfileDirectory` function.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

std::wstring get_home()
{
    DWORD size = 0;
    HANDLE token = GetCurrentProcessToken();

    // get the size needed for the buffer.
    GetUserProfileDirectoryW(token, NULL, &size);
    if (size == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to get required size.\n");
    }

    // this won't work pre-C++11, since strings weren't guaranteed
    // to be continuous
    std::wstring home(size, 0);
    if (!GetUserProfileDirectoryW(token, &home[0], &size)) {
        throw std::runtime_error(("Unable to get home directory.\n");
    }

    return home;
}
```

If you would like to rely on environment variables, this is not so easy, but the best solution is to check `USERPROFILE`, then `HOME`, then `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`, and if none of those are set, then `SystemDrive` as a fallback. This works out to:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

std::wstring get_home()
{
    // check USERPROFILE
    wchar_t *home = _wgetenv(L"USERPROFILE");
    if (home != nullptr) {
        return std::wstring(home);
    }

    // check HOME
    home = _wgetenv(L"HOME");
    if (home != nullptr) {
        return std::wstring(home);
    }

    // combine HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH
    wchar_t *drive = _wgetenv(L"HOMEDRIVE");
    wchar_t *path = _wgetenv(L"HOMEPATH");
    if (drive != nullptr && path != nullptr) {
        // "c:", "\users\{user}"
        return std::wstring(drive) + std::wstring(path);
    }

    // try SystemDrive
    home = _wgetenv(L"SystemDrive");
    if (home != nullptr) {
        return std::wstring(home);
    } else {
        return std::wstring(L"c:");
    }
}
```

**Why not WordExp?**

`wordexp` is not guaranteed to be a part of Windows compilers, and won't work well on Windows. Also, `HOME` is not guaranteed to be set on Windows. You should use `(_w)getenv`. Also, `wordexp` does shell expansion, which means many other symbols (including `*`, character sets, and other environment variables) will be expanded, which may not be desired. This is simple, cross-platform, and limited in scope.

Comment: Windows also has the [`GetUserProfileDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762280.aspx) function.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That is remarkably simpler. And XP-compatible. Thank you. Editing now.

Comment: Actually, wait, @MilesBudnek, how do I get the token for the currently logged-on user without attempting to log-on a user?

Comment: You can use [`OpenProcessToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295.aspx) (and [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179.aspx)) to get a token for the user under which the process is running.

Comment: Oh, or [`GetCurrentProcessToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt643211.aspx), I guess that's a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderHuszagh. I am using Ubuntu; I just edited the question and details. Please check.

Comment: @Mat_python Then you want the first example, since Ubuntu is a POSIX-like OS. It **cannot** and **should not** be done at compile-time, you want it at run-time. If you would like, you can define an `extern const std::string` to store a global variable that is initialized when the program starts up, and that variable can be accessed from a header.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Is there a way to do with `static constexpr const char* FOLDER_PATH` and not `extern const std::string`? Thank you.

Comment: @Mat_python. No. By definition, no. Absolutely, completely, utterly impossible, and even if it **was** possible, you **would** not want to do that. Imagine only ever being able to use a program on the same  computer and user that compiled it....

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Aah. Thanks. Makes sense now. I will have to use `extern const std::string`. But, can I just define it this way: `extern const std::string FOLDER_PATH = get_home() + "/catkin_ws/src/abc/pqr/xyz"`

Comment: @Mat_python, You don't instantiate a variable using extern. But you can always do `const std::string FOLDER_PATH = get_home() + "/local/path/to/file"`, sure. Just make sure you don't mess with static initialization order fiasco.