# How to replace the home directory with a tilde? Linux

Tags: c++, linux, tilde-expansion

I'm currently making a shell in C++ and I've been able to output the absolute directory as the prompt with getcwd(), however when the user reaches the home directory I would like to output a tilde instead of the home directory.

So for example instead of

> [bb@bbmachine bb]

I would like to output

> [bb@bbmachine ~]

How would I do something like that?

Comment: There's the `$HOME` environment variable. So just get that value and replace the `~` with it or vice versa.

Comment: No. Do not write function  that already exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991241/how-do-i-achieve-tilde-expansion-in-c

Comment: No, OP does not want to *expand* `~` but to replace `/home/user/` with `~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read first about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), notably [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). For the *expansion* of path starting with tilde `~` consider [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) and [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html).

For showing a path starting with the home directory, you need to get that home directory. You could use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) like `getenv("HOME")` (there are rare pathological cases where that could fail) or [getpwuid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) (or even [getpw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpw.3.html)) on the result of [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html). The home directory (when `getpwuid` succeeds) is given by the `pw_dir` field. See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) (and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)...)

There are rare pathological cases where `getenv("HOME")` and `getpwuid(getuid())` fail or give unconsistent results (about the user's home directory). I believe you should detect failure, but you might not care about inconsistency. See also [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html). You could even consider the GNU specific [secure_getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/secure_getenv.3.html).

BTW, you could cache the home directory, i.e. compute it once in your shell. It is unlikely to change often.

You could also decide to canonicalize a path using [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

You certainly have corner cases: do you want to display `/home/john/../mary/` as `~/../mary`, as `/home/mary/`, as `~mary`, (or even leave it as `/home/john/../mary`)  assuming your process is running under `john` uid? (and both `john` and `mary` exist as user names in [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) with home directories `/home/john/` and `/home/mary/`). And what about `/home/john/../../proc/$$/maps` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html))?

You need to decide how you'll handle these corner or pathological cases, and *document* the behavior of your shell.

<sup>(the functions mentioned have a C API, you might want to use `extern "C"` in your C++ code)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what @TheDude said. Here's some pseudocode.

```
#include "pwd.h"
#include <string>
string home=getenv("HOME");
int location=yourPathString.find(home);
length=home.length();
originalLength=yourPathString.length();
string newString=yourPathString.substr(0,location);
newString+= "~";
newString+= yourPathString.substr(location+length,originalLength);
```

This should give you the right idea, but remember, documentation and Google are your friends.[String Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: I just looked online, you can combine several of these line with STD::string::replace

Comment: Your code forgot to handle (unlikely) failures, and `pwd.h` is probably not needed

Comment: I forgot what library getenv() is in. And I'm sure there will be problems. There always are.

Comment: `getenv` is from `stdlib.h`. `man` pages like [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) are helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could use [wordexp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) something like this:

```
#include <wordexp.h>

// put all the horrible bits into a function
std::string wordexp(std::string var, int flags = 0)
{
    wordexp_t p;
    if(!wordexp(var.c_str(), &p, flags))
    {
        if(p.we_wordc && p.we_wordv[0])
            var = p.we_wordv[0];
        wordfree(&p);
    }
    return var;
}

int main()
{
    auto const HOME = wordexp("~");

    std::string path = "/home/galik/wibble";

    if(path.find(HOME) == 0)
        path.replace(0, HOME.size(), "~");

    std::cout << path << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
~/wibble
```

Comment: You don't need `wordexp` to expand `~`, since you could use `getenv("HOME")` which is shorter (you do need to check that `getenv` does not return `NULL`, which is pathological here)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch True but if you are writing a shell (like the OP is) then `wordexpand` is probably something to keep handy. Also I like the symmetry with testing against `~` itself in order to detect `~` it feels more robust.