# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68) when trying to open a file

Tags: c

So I tried to open and read a file this way but I get:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68) it says that the pointer is null
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    FILE * fp;
    
    fp = fopen("labb.txt", "r");
    
    char line[200];
    
    while(!feof(fp)){
       
            fgets(line, 200, fp);
            puts(line);
        
        
    }fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is fp null....?

Comment: fp is null i tried multiple ways to call the file but none seem to work

Comment: Switch to `while (fgets(line, 200, fp)) { puts(line); }` and see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1606345)

Comment: make sure that the file labb.txt is in the project folder. try to make new file (`fp = fopen("labb.txt", "w");`) and wirte to it, after that run the origin code to check if it work

Comment: @jacobgalam ***no!*** That will overwrite the file and erase all the content. OP is trying to read data from it, so that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least three problems in your code:

1. This is not going to work:

   ```
   fp = fopen(fileLocation, "r"); // fileLocation is "~/Desktop/labb.txt"
   ```

   The C library stdio functions do not know what `~` is. It's not going to expand `~` for you. You should expand it yourself or change method. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991241/how-do-i-achieve-tilde-expansion-in-c) for more information.

   If the file is in the same directory as the one you are running the program in, you can use `./labb.txt`. If not, you can always use the absolute path to the file, or figure out a correct relative path. E.G. if `labb.txt` is in `/home/you/Desktop` and your program is in `/home/you` you should use `./Desktop/labb.txt`.
2. You do not check for errors. You should check `fp != NULL` after the call to `fopen`. Opening a file can always fail, always check for errors.

   ```
   fp = fopen(...);
   if (fp == NULL) {
       perror("fopen failed");
       return 1;
   }
   ```

   The same goes for `fgets`, reading a file can always fail.

   ```
   char *res = fgets(line, 200, fp);
   if (res == NULL) {
       perror("fgets failed");
       return 1;
   }
   ```
3. `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/3889449) to understand why.