# Can paths for libssh2 be relative?

Tags: c, libssh2

I'm trying to use https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile_ex.html with `"~/.ssh/id_ed25519"` but I feel like it's not expanding the path? It doesn't say in the docs what kind of paths are supported. Does anyone know if this should work?

Comment: Do you want to use relative paths like `some/dir/file` or do you ask on how to convert `~` to the full path of the home directory?

Comment: I was interested in the tilde ~ but if someone knows an answer for both that's also useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I achieve tilde expansion in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991241/how-do-i-achieve-tilde-expansion-in-c)

Comment: I was interested in how libssh2 handles relative paths when passed as parameter since I'm consuming it from a Rust codebase so I was wondering if I can skip doing tilde expansion myself