# C++ stat() function not finding remote file

Tags: c++, linux, remote-debugging, targeting, remote-development

I'm using Visual Studio and I'm connected to my Linux machine using remote development (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-170). I'm trying to call the [stat()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/stat.htm) function to find if a file exists, but it can never find it. I believe this is because; in the documentation for [stat()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/stat.htm), it says

> If you are accessing a remote file through the Network File System,
> update operations to file permissions at the server are not reflected
> at the client until updates to data that is stored locally by the
> Network File System take place. (Several options on the Add Mounted
> File System (ADDMFS) command determine the time between refresh
> operations of local data.) Access to a remote file may also fail due
> to different mappings of user IDs (UID) or group IDs (GID) on the
> local and remote systems.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm wondering if there is a way to specify a remote file path though visual studio or something?

Comment: There's a function called `access`, you could try that.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm sure you will find that the C library function `access()` calls the system call `stat()` under the hood.

Comment: On which machine are you calling `stat`?

Comment: @DavisHerring Please look at the link, I'm doing remote development and the files are on the linux machine, I dont know how else to say it.

Comment: @Katianie: Wait, you said both things: “calling stat on my PC” and “executing the program on my linux pc”.  Those can’t both be true for any one execution; the link implies it’s the latter, but then if the file is also on the target machine why would you need a remote filename?

Comment: @DavisHerring Ok I deleted the comment that confused you. Go with the link and what I wrote and how Paul understood it. I don't know how else to spell it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program is being built on the remote machine, presumably it is also being run there (unless you are *also* doing cross-compilation, which is a very different thing).  You therefore do not need any special syntax to refer to files on that machine (which is remote for your editor but **not** your process).

You still have to worry about the usual questions like case-sensitivity and your current working directory (for the process, not the editor); the bit in the documentation you found is about network filesystems mounted *by* the target machine.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I'm almost 100% sure I'm calling stat the correct way stat("~/testfiles/test.txt", &buffer); but it always returns error.

Comment: @Katianie: And there’s [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15991241/8586227) I was (unknowingly) trying to get you to ask.

Comment: Yea looks like a call to chdir("/home/"); before calling stat("/home/ed/testfiles/test.txt", &buffer) fixes the issue. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Katianie: The `chdir` there doesn’t do anything for the `stat`, which is already using an absolute filename, but good.